# Unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server VS 2015 (all projects)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

So i finaly had a nice part of my project done but then i had to try the application on phone which required me to configure IIS express.

Now i have a lovely message box on my screen telling me that ISS express web server won't start.

I have tried everything i could find on stackoverflow but it is still not working. (deleting IIS epxress, changing web server port, checked firewall, used netsh delete and add and more)
IIS express isnt working for any of my projects and i get the message.

What could be problem, how can i solve it ?

--edit
I know im late, i went home the other day.
Here is the error image.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoLMT.png)

--solved

I reinstalled VS 2015 and everything with it, took a while but it finaly works now.

--edit 2
Now that the previous error is gone i have a new one :D (gaben pls)

When i start my application there is no problem at all but when i try to connect with my browser it says "Can not connect"

And when i try to connect to my database i get error 40.
Offcourse i have tried some solutions but it wont work again..

Comment: Can you see this error message?

Comment: Yes i get a message box everytime i run an mvc application

Comment: Sorry I meant can *we* see the error message? (can you share it?)